# Logstash indexing JSON arrays

Tags: json, logstash

Logstash is awesome. I can send it JSON like this (multi-lined for readability):

```
{
  "a": "one"
  "b": {
    "alpha":"awesome"
  }
}
```

And then query for that line in kibana using the search term `b.alpha:awesome`. Nice.

However I now have a JSON log line like this:

```
{
  "different":[
    {
      "this": "one",
      "that": "uno"
    },
    {
      "this": "two"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'd like to be able to find this line with a search like `different.this:two`  (or `different.this:one`, or `different.that:uno`)

If I was using Lucene directly I'd iterate through the `different` array, and generate a new search index for each hash within it, but Logstash currently seems to ingest that line like this:

> different: {this: one, that: uno}, {this: two}

Which isn't going to help me searching for log lines using `different.this` or `different.that`.

Any got any thoughts as to a codec, filter or code change I can make to enable this?

Comment: What is your desired JSON format after indexing the array?

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own [filter](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/extending/example-add-a-new-filter) (copy & paste, rename the class name, the `config_name` and rewrite the `filter(event)` method) or modify the current [JSON](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/filters/json) filter ([source](https://github.com/elasticsearch/logstash/blob/v1.4.0/lib/logstash/filters/json.rb) on Github)

You can find the JSON filter (Ruby class) source code in the following path `logstash-1.x.x\lib\logstash\filters` named as `json.rb`. The JSON filter parse the content as JSON as follows

```
begin
  # TODO(sissel): Note, this will not successfully handle json lists
  # like your text is '[ 1,2,3 ]' JSON.parse gives you an array (correctly)
  # which won't merge into a hash. If someone needs this, we can fix it
  # later.
  dest.merge!(JSON.parse(source))

  # If no target, we target the root of the event object. This can allow
  # you to overwrite @timestamp. If so, let's parse it as a timestamp!
  if !@target && event[TIMESTAMP].is_a?(String)
    # This is a hack to help folks who are mucking with @timestamp during
    # their json filter. You aren't supposed to do anything with
    # "@timestamp" outside of the date filter, but nobody listens... ;)
    event[TIMESTAMP] = Time.parse(event[TIMESTAMP]).utc
  end

  filter_matched(event)
rescue => e
  event.tag("_jsonparsefailure")
  @logger.warn("Trouble parsing json", :source => @source,
               :raw => event[@source], :exception => e)
  return
end
```

You can modify the parsing procedure to modify the original JSON

```
  json  = JSON.parse(source)
  if json.is_a?(Hash)
    json.each do |key, value| 
        if value.is_a?(Array)
            value.each_with_index do |object, index|
                #modify as you need
                object["index"]=index
            end
        end
    end
  end
  #save modified json
  ......
  dest.merge!(json)
```

then you can modify your config file to use the/your new/modified JSON filter and place in `\logstash-1.x.x\lib\logstash\config`

This is mine `elastic_with_json.conf` with a modified `json.rb` filter

```
input{
    stdin{

    }
}filter{
    json{
        source => "message"
    }
}output{
    elasticsearch{
        host=>localhost
    }stdout{

    }
}
```

if you want to use your new filter you can configure it with the `config_name`

```
class LogStash::Filters::Json_index < LogStash::Filters::Base

  config_name "json_index"
  milestone 2
  ....
end
```

and configure it

```
input{
    stdin{

    }
}filter{
    json_index{
        source => "message"
    }
}output{
    elasticsearch{
        host=>localhost
    }stdout{

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For a quick and dirty hack, I used the `Ruby` filter and below code , no need to use the out of box 'json' filter anymore

```
input {
  stdin{}
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message","(?<json_raw>.*)"]
  }
  ruby {
    init => "
      def parse_json obj, pname=nil, event
         obj = JSON.parse(obj) unless obj.is_a? Hash
         obj = obj.to_hash unless obj.is_a? Hash

         obj.each {|k,v|
         p = pname.nil?? k : pname
         if v.is_a? Array
           v.each_with_index {|oo,ii|               
             parse_json_array(oo,ii,p,event)
           }
           elsif v.is_a? Hash
             parse_json(v,p,event)
           else
             p = pname.nil?? k : [pname,k].join('.')
             event[p] = v
           end
         }
        end

        def parse_json_array obj, i,pname, event
          obj = JSON.parse(obj) unless obj.is_a? Hash
          pname_ = pname
          if obj.is_a? Hash
            obj.each {|k,v|
              p=[pname_,i,k].join('.')
              if v.is_a? Array
                v.each_with_index {|oo,ii|
                  parse_json_array(oo,ii,p,event)
                }
              elsif v.is_a? Hash
                parse_json(v,p, event)
              else
                event[p] = v
              end
            }
          else
            n = [pname_, i].join('.')
            event[n] = obj
          end
        end
      "
      code => "parse_json(event['json_raw'].to_s,nil,event) if event['json_raw'].to_s.include? ':'"
    }


  }

output {
  stdout{codec => rubydebug}
}
```

Test json structure

```
{"id":123, "members":[{"i":1, "arr":[{"ii":11},{"ii":22}]},{"i":2}], "im_json":{"id":234, "members":[{"i":3},{"i":4}]}}
```

and this is whats output

```
      {
           "message" => "{\"id\":123, \"members\":[{\"i\":1, \"arr\":[{\"ii\":11},{\"ii\":22}]},{\"i\":2}], \"im_json\":{\"id\":234, \"members\":[{\"i\":3},{\"i\":4}]}}",
          "@version" => "1",
        "@timestamp" => "2014-07-25T00:06:00.814Z",
              "host" => "Leis-MacBook-Pro.local",
          "json_raw" => "{\"id\":123, \"members\":[{\"i\":1, \"arr\":[{\"ii\":11},{\"ii\":22}]},{\"i\":2}], \"im_json\":{\"id\":234, \"members\":[{\"i\":3},{\"i\":4}]}}",
                "id" => 123,
       "members.0.i" => 1,
"members.0.arr.0.ii" => 11,
"members.0.arr.1.ii" => 22,
       "members.1.i" => 2,
           "im_json" => 234,
       "im_json.0.i" => 3,
       "im_json.1.i" => 4
      }
```

Comment: as time going this solution should still work but in a clumsy way - I'd say. It's better for a predictable json structure to use predefined mappings, and for un-predicatable jsons with arrays inside, you could still do similar thing but in your own custom filters rather than a ruby filter

Comment: In recent elasticsearch releases, you can't have periods in field names.  If you're drawn to this solution, use another character.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I liked is the ruby filter because that requires us to not write another filter. However, that solution creates fields that are on the "root" of JSON and it's hard to keep track of how the original document looked.

I came up with something similar that's easier to follow and is a recursive solution so it's cleaner.

```
ruby {
    init => "
        def arrays_to_hash(h)
          h.each do |k,v|
            # If v is nil, an array is being iterated and the value is k.
            # If v is not nil, a hash is being iterated and the value is v.
            value = v || k
            if value.is_a?(Array)
                # "value" is replaced with "value_hash" later.
                value_hash = {}
                value.each_with_index do |v, i|
                    value_hash[i.to_s] = v
                end
                h[k] = value_hash
            end

            if value.is_a?(Hash) || value.is_a?(Array)
              arrays_to_hash(value)
            end
          end
        end
      "
      code => "arrays_to_hash(event.to_hash)"
}
```

It converts arrays to has with each key as the index number. More details:- http://blog.abhijeetr.com/2016/11/logstashelasticsearch-best-way-to.html