# How should I filter multiple fields with the same name in logstash?

Tags: json, regex, elasticsearch, logstash, tsung

I'm putting tsung logs into ElasticSearch (ES) so that I can filter, visualize and compare results using Kibana.

I'm using logstash and its JSON parsing filter to push tsung logs in JSON format to ES.

Tsung logs are a bit complicated (IMO) with array objects into array objects, multiple-lines event, and several fields having the same name such as "value" in my example hereafter.

I would like to transform this event:

```
{
 "stats":[
  {"timestamp": 1317413861,  "samples": [
   {"name": "users", "value": 0, "max": 1},
   {"name": "users_count", "value": 1, "total": 1},
   {"name": "finish_users_count", "value": 1, "total": 1}]}]}
```

into this:

```
{"timestamp": 1317413861},{"users_value":0},{"users_max":1},{"users_count_value":1},{"users_count_total":1},{"finish_users_count_value":1},{"finish_users_count_total":1}
```

Since the entire tsung log file is forwarded to logstash at the end of a performance test campaign, I'm thinking about using regex to remove *CR* and unusefull *stats* and *samples* arrays before sending the event to logstash in order to simplify a little bit.

And then, I would use those kind of JSON filter options:

```
add_field => {"%{name}_value" => "%{value}"}
add_field => {"%{name}_max" => "%{max}"}
add_field => {"%{name}_total" => "%{total}"}
```

But how should I handle the fact that there are many *value* fields in one event for instance? What is the best thing to do?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems to me that you should be able to iterate through each dictionary in samples to do the transformation without having to resort to a Regular Expression.  I am looking at this from a Python perspective so I know that would work, concatenate the value for "name" to each of the successive keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feels like the ruby{} filter would be needed here.  Loop across the entries in the 'samples' field, and construct your own fields based on the name/value/total/max.

There are examples of this type of behavior elsewhere on SO.

Comment: After learning basic ruby syntax, I inspired a lot from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067346/logstash-indexing-json-arrays